# Centering Images over text

Tags: html, css

So I have 6 images with text "Attatched" to them. Currently, I'd like to center them to the middle of the screen, as I am making a portal. Right now, they're in the upper left hand corner, and I cannot for the life of me center them correctly.

My CSS and HTML, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```css
body {
background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
.image {
    float: left;
}
.text {
 float: auto;
    text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/home.png" height="130" width="160"/></a>
    <div class="text">
        Home
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the margin for the image and change the display to block. Then the image will center align to the middle of screen.

```
.image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

for more details see this [link](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin of the image using "*margin: auto*"